# how to check unused promo codes in google developer console

Tags: android, google-play

I need to know how many promo codes in my app has been used (for example from 50 promo codes) and also one more question, how can I check report for products that sold by promo code.In google play console I can only see the report for real purchased products.

Comment: I'd like to know this too